# Last message sent logic issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I'm attempting to identify the last message sent in a conversation for a set of conversations in SQL. I can get back the correct users and ID's no problem, but the last message and the time it was sent are coming back as the same for both conversations, whereas I need the last message sent in that particular conversation.

Here's the SQL I'm using:

```
SELECT ConversationId,
       (SELECT Username FROM dbo.[User] WHERE (UserId = dbo.Conversation.FromUser)) AS FromUser,
       (SELECT Username
        FROM dbo.[User] User_1
        WHERE (UserId = dbo.Conversation.ToUser)) AS ToUser,
       (SELECT TOP (1)
               MessageBody
        FROM dbo.ConversationMessage
        WHERE (ConversationId = ConversationId)
        ORDER BY MessageDateTime DESC) AS LastMessageBody,
       (SELECT TOP (1)
               CONVERT(varchar(5), MessageDateTime, 114) AS Expr1
        FROM dbo.ConversationMessage ConversationMessage_1
        WHERE (ConversationId = ConversationId)
        ORDER BY MessageDateTime DESC) AS LastMessageTime
FROM dbo.Conversation;
```

And here's the result set I'm getting back, just for clarity:
[image]

LastMessageBody and LastMessageTime, should both be unique and since the ConversationId's are both unique I can't see why the same message should be returned each time. My understanding was that the individual row's ConversationId would be used in the where clause just like the UserId in the other columns?

Comment: Your query is way more complicated than your description.  I have a hard time figuring out what the real question is.

Comment: This is a terrible way to get your data. Try to use joins instead of subqueries

Comment: To explain why you get duplicated values, the condition `WHERE (ConversationId = ConversationId)` is always `true`, you aren't correlating the value in the subquery with the outer `Conversation` table

Comment: I did try a join at first, but because I was joining table more than once I couldn't get it to work

Comment: @WebDevelopWolf Provide some sample data and your expected result in well formatted text. It'll help people understand what you need better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, this is a massive stab in the dark, however, it *might* be what you're after. There's no sample data or expected results here, so if this isn't what you need, then provide both.

I've also got rid of those awful subqueries and replaced them with `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
       C.ConversationId,
       Uf.Username AS FromUser,
       Ut.Username AS ToUser,
       CM.MessageBody AS LastMessageBody,
       CONVERT(time(0),CM.MessageDateTime) AS LastMessageTime
FROM dbo.[Conversation] C
     JOIN dbo.[User] Uf ON C.FromUser = Uf.UserId
     JOIN dbo.[User] Ut ON C.ToUser = Ut.UserId
     JOIN dbo.ConversationMessage CM ON C.ConversationId = CM.ConversationId
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.ConversationId ORDER BY CM.MessageDateTime DESC);
```

Comment: though I did upvote, I don't think that op wants a `TOP 1`

Comment: @Lamak Mm, as i said, it is a massive stab in the dark. I used `TOP 1 WITH TIES` as the OP states *"last message sent in a conversation for a set of conversations"*. Which, to me, implies they are after the latest message in a conversation. Without knowing anything specific though...

Comment: That is very nearly there :) - I just need convert the time to just a timestamp :) - the data returned is right though (no of rows etc.)

Comment: @WebDevelopWolf when you say timestamp, do you mean `time`?

Comment: I do yeah - I don't want the full date, just the time as in `15:30`

Comment: @WebDevelopWolf i've added a `CONVERT` to the `time` datatype. If you don't want the seconds, really you should handle that in your presentation layer. Changing things like dates and times to a `varchar` is normally a bad idea unless (for some very odd reason) you're presentation layer can't handle presentation formats.

Comment: To expand on my prior comment, `time` and `timestamp` are very different things in SQL Server. Try `SELECT CONVERT(time, GETDATE()), CONVERT(timestamp,GETDATE());`. `timestamp` actually has nothing to do with `time`.

Comment: Getting closer lol - just need the second dropped from the time - I think that's why I converted it to a varchar - at the moment it's returning `15:30:00` and I need `15:30`

Comment: @WebDevelopWolf As I said, handle that in your presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have multiple tables in a query, *always* use table aliases and qualified column names.  This is your problem.

Here is an example of how to fix it:

```
SELECT . . .
       (SELECT TOP (1) cm.MessageBody
        FROM dbo.ConversationMessage cm
        WHERE cm.ConversationId = c.ConversationId
        ORDER BY cm.MessageDateTime DESC
       ) AS LastMessageBody,
       . . .
 FROM dbo.Conversation c;
```

When *all* column names are properly qualified, your query should work as you intend.